How are continuous wavevector components dealt with in vacuum energy calculation?
I'm currently working on calculations relating to the Casimir effect, the first and foremost of which is solving for the energy content of a vacuum (I'm starting with the simple two-conducting-plates scenario before trying something more complicated). I know that the zero-point energy for the quantum harmonic oscillator is $E=\frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega$, so to find the zero-point energy between two plates a distance $a$ apart you sum over all the allowable modes
$$E=\frac{1}{2}\hbar\sum_n\omega_n=\frac{1}{2}\hbar c\sum k$$
for wavenumbers $k_n$. In the case of two conducting plates parallel to the $x$ axis, the wavenumbers are
$$k=\sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{a^2}+k_y^2+k_z^2}$$
for integers $n$ and continuous axial wavenumbers $k_y$ and $k_z$. In the one-dimensional case I would simply say that $k=\frac{n\pi}{a}$, then the vacuum energy becomes
$$E=\frac{1}{2}\hbar c\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\pi}{a}=\frac{\hbar c\pi}{2a}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac{\hbar c\pi}{24a},$$
since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac{1}{12}$ by regularization, which more or less resembles the $-\frac{\hbar c\pi^2}{720a^4}$ that the classic Casimir effect gives. But that's in one dimension; in three dimensions, with the plates only restricting wavenumbers in the $x$-direction, the $k_y$ and $k_z$ components of the summand are continuous.
How do I deal with these continuous components of the wavenumber? I would think it possible to integrate over the continuous $k_y$ and $k_z$ spectra somehow but I'm not sure what the numerical method for that is.

Does this help? It does the integral.
